# SPA post requests in cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, post, single-page-application, aws-api-gateway, elm

I have created a cloudfront distribution with two origins (s3 bucket and aws apigateway). The s3 bucket serves my Elm spa successfully but when I try to send a post request via the SPA to my api gateway I get a 403. This is my elm post request:

```
testReq : Cmd Msg
testReq =
  request
    { method = "POST"
    , headers = []
    , url = "https://xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/api/testy/gettalent"
    , body = jsonBody testBody
    , expect = Http.expectWhatever Resp
    , timeout = Nothing
    , tracker = Nothing
    }
```

Comment: Please post the full error, if its 403 cross-origin rejected, you probably need to enable cors on your API gateway,

Answer (score 0):

Usually, HTTP 403 means access denied, In your case, I believe that your website domain and the API domains are different. Therefore this could be access denied due to "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" error.

if that's the case, you should enable `CORS` on your API resource method.

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: I followed this guide https://advancedweb.hu/how-cloudfront-solves-cors-problems/ to avoid CORS issues.

Comment: No I haven't. This is my terraform file: https://pastebin.com/bAd87jSn

@ArunK My API gateway is working because I can get it to respond with postman if I send a request directly to it, however accessing it via cloudfront results in Forbidden.

Comment: The error I get is thrown from my elm SPA `BadStatus 403`. The browser web console does not report any CORS errors.

Comment: trying to understand, what's the purpose of configuring CloudFront for your API gateway api.

Comment: This is to avoid having to deal with CORS. The point is the SPA and the Apigateway will be on the same domain i.e no CORS.

Comment: can you send me the generated clouformation template

Comment: I tried to set up a CloudFront for an example API, it worked when I mapped the default caching behavior without any prefix such as `/api/*`. it didn't work with `/api/*`  . still trying to fx it

Comment: I resolved it: https://pastebin.com/8AujUXZg
Basically I setup a simple API gateway by itself in cloudfront following this: https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-api-gateway-with-cloudfront/

You have to be careful what `path_pattern` you specify as cloud front constructs urls for you automatically.

Comment: @Jimbo You should accept and up-vote this answer if you found it helpful.